# Specify required argument type of function as arrow function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to require an arrow function as type for function argument in some way in typescript? For example, if I use publish-subscriber model, I pass a function of listener to 'server' object, that call this function when a publisher send message to the topic. And If I pass not arrow function it will throw an error if 'this' is used. So, I would like to find a way to add this type of restriction to make such a mistake impossible.

Comment: Which error it will throw ? And personnally I use this and it works

Comment: No, there is no way in typescript to differentiate functions from arrow functions as types.

Comment: @Elikill58 [playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwFgAoZc5SAZzFQjAAsB7AEwApHgqAuNLPAJS8Abk2AtSAX1KkEAGzhUqfHPmABbAA5yI6iOGUZVhUhWSaowYXEjIETAK7hoyALzIADAG4ZZCtVp6ZnYBEz8zck4qADp7J0goAGpEn3CI+xAqJh1ouSYAcw4GLljHZygBVLNJVNMKOCgoJgB3CBYAFQgaOkZWN2Q2UNcAPkpimICe4MHU6RJZJkywZHV+fHcQCGaVPBnfVdVoyaDWQeQAenPkfKY+gG0AGUwAcQBdXgBGXwyaFZOWfoHPBHLqBXoAy7IBZLZANJqtFhTPruIG4aJwlptTrdf61EgYhFIkJeC5XG73J5vXgAJlIenBM1JyDuAFEAEps95jLjIHlOFgQGCgNrkIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't differentiate between the different ways of declaring a function. But what you do is declare the type of `this`, and if your function call would result in an incompatible type for `this`, then a type error is raised.

For example:

```
interface MyObj {
    testMethod(this: MyObj): void // declare `this` as `MyObj` in this function.
}

const myObj: MyObj = {
    testMethod() {}
}
```

Now if you call that normally:

```
myObj.testMethod() // good
```

But if you call it the wrong way:

```
const method = myObj.testMethod
method() // The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'MyObj'.(2684)
```

So if you type `this` properly, typescript should enforce the rest.

[Read more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwFgAoZc5SAZzFQjAAsB7AEwApHgqAuNLPAJS8Abk2AtSAX1KkETEDWQBbfrl4Yc+ALyFSFShBp1GrNgN1l9FAPTWAdA70VpJF6RWa71WvWbtztsgA5kysMiRyCmDKvqzIOh54XoY+JhIkSrH+yIEAKgwoAOScVIXIkZAAHtFMMJToAA5FouJlXMggTNFwVFTAQSBw2AA2KGBMMWmFVMjFDFxltfVNsxp4hXZsAEwAbAAcACwCQA)

---

Another example showing the three different ways to declare a method:

```
interface MyObj {
    testMethod(this: MyObj): void // declare `this` as `MyObj` in this function.
}

const myObjA: MyObj = {
    testMethod: function() {
        this // good
    }
}

const myObjB: MyObj = {
    testMethod() {
        this // good
    }
}

const myObjC: MyObj = {
    testMethod: () => {
        this // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.(7017)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1&strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwFgAoZc5SAZzFQjAAsB7AEwApHgqAuNLPAJS8Abk2AtkAeknIWEBABs4UFAANOVVcjhVkqjDlxbQlBl2QwAriARhgTEADpSAX1KkEDmsgC2-XACCvAZ4yAC8hKQUlBA0dIysvFY2dg5sApFk0RQaUjIA5kysURRuJGUeXmC+-gBCwf7hmdHUtPTM7BnEWdmm5tLIhcU9yGUVJJ4g3n6GAMINhk3dLbFtCSy86eEAfM29fboDAKIKED4Q4MjAPgAOCsAIwGAK6MgMOtogyADkcCDo30o6BuKGw8jglioKDAwJQ3xhIKYMEGCiY2DgCgAKmYqID3roQEwriA5AAPZBUYD5EBwMCWFSONgAdgADABGJkCErkMZAA)